# SessionId for an IP using Socket.io in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am doing a chat application using socket.io in Node js.
I have to create a sessionId for an IP connecting to the node js server.

```
socket.on('adduser', function(username){
          var address = socket.handshake.address;
            console.log(address);
        sessionId = socket.address.sessionid;
        console.log("sessionId="+sessionId);
        ........
        });
```

I get an error;
 Cannot read property 'sessionid' of undefined

Please Advice

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('adduser', function(username){
          var address = socket.handshake.address;
            console.log(address);
       // sessionId = socket.address.sessionid;
        sessionId = socket.id;
        console.log("sessionId="+sessionId);
        ........
        });
```